# Manually spawn stateful pod instances

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, kubernetes-statefulset

I'm working on a project where I need to spawn 1 instance per user (customer).

I figured it makes sense to create some sort of manager to handle that and host it somewhere. Kubernetes seems like a good choice since it can be hosted virtually anywhere and it will automate a lot of things (e.g. ensuring instances keep running on failure).

All entities are in Python and have a corresponding Flask API.

```
                         InstanceManager         Instance (user1)
                          .-----------.            .--------.
POST /instances/user3 --> |           | ---------- |        |---vol1
                          |           |            '--------'
                          |           | -----.     
                          '...........'       \   Instance (user2)
                                               \   .--------.
                                                '- |        |---vol2
                                                   '--------'
```

Now I can't seem to figure out how to translate this into Kubernetes

My thinking:

- Instance is a `StatefulSet` since I want the data to be maintained through restarts.
- InstanceManager is a `Service` with a database attached to track user to instance IP (for health checks, etc).

I'm pretty lost on how to make `InstanceManager` spawn a new instance on an incoming POST request. I did a lot of digging (Operators, namespaces, etc.) but nothing seems straightforward. Namely I don't seem to even be able to do that via `kubectl`. Am I thinking totally wrong on how Kubernetes works?

Comment: K8s is great for dynamically starting pods (1 or more containers in each pod).  But there is a lot involved in persistence.  "StatefulSet" merely means the pod ID is predicable - ie: 0 or 1 or 2... instead of a ggname.  You might look at systems that are running jython notebooks for inspiration for the pod-per-user model for hints.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some progress and thought to share.

Essentially you need to interact with Kubernetes REST API directly **instead of applying a static yaml or using `kubectl`**, ideally with one of the numerous clients out there.

In our case there's two options:

1. Create a namespace per user and then a service in that namespace
2. Create a new service with a unique name for each user

The first approach seems more sensible since using namespaces gives a lot of other benefits (network control, resource allocation, etc.).

The service itself can be pointing to a `statefulset` or a `pod` depending on the situation.

There's another gotcha (and possibly more). Namespaces, pod names, etc, they all need to conform to RFC 1123. So for namespaces, you can't simply use email addresses or even base64. You'll need to use something like `user-100` and have a mapping table to map back to an actual user.